# Graphics Card Problems

Tags: windows-8.1, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver, 32-vs-64-bit

I've just bought a new gaming PC. I installed Windows 8.1 (64bit) on my PC as that is the minimum requirements for most games. However my driver file says my graphics card is for a 32 bit system so I basically can't run games. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Basically you need the 64bit driver from the manufacturer, if there is one available. I can post a link to one once I have the graphics card information.

Comment: I have a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4gb. I dont have a clue how to get the drivers. Im new to all this, i would appriciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver to download for your card would be located at: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/113442/en-us.

When running the installer, you can select "Custom (Advanced)", then check the box that says "Perform a clean installation" to remove the previously installed 32bit driver. You can also custom select which items to install with the new driver.

Comment: No problem! If you run into any problems getting the updated driver to work just reply.

Comment: Yep - glad you got it working!